# About the degree of a field extension of the field of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, rational-functions

There is a solution to a problem but I'm not quite sure why $[\mathbb{Q}(x) : \mathbb Q(y)] = 2$ here. Here the field is rational functions instead of the usual field extension so I don't know how to figure out $\mathbb Q(x)$ is a 2-dim $\mathbb Q(y)$-vector space.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function field setting is adding confusion, let $L=\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(y)$. Then $L=K(x)$, and here, as the author shows, $x$ satisfies a quadratic equation over $K$, so $[L:K]\leq 2$. But since we know that $L/K$ is nontrivial, the degree must be exactly $2$.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that L = K(x). I think the key to notice this is that $\frac1{a(y)x + b(y)}$ should be in $K(x)$ since it is a field. ($a, b$ are polynomials).